# SQL COUNT() doesn't work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT person.id,
       person.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT fruit.apple) AS "Red Apple",
       fruit.*
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   tree
        ORDER  BY color DESC) AS fruit
       INNER JOIN person
         ON fruit.id = person.id
WHERE  person.name = 'John Smith'
```

Now, that code is working before I put in the `COUNT(DISTINCT fruit.apple) AS "Apple"`. what is wrong with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i bet the query returns exactly what you have asked it to return.  what is your data? what results do you expect?

Comment: Define "Not working". Also what is the purpose of `ORDER  BY color DESC` in the derived table definition? Also `INNER JOIN people    ON fruit.id = person.id` definitely won't work. The table name changes midway through.

Comment: @MartinSmith : Not working like this `mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

Comment: @JohnSmith - Please post your **actual** query and explain what it is intended to do.

Comment: the `color` actually `date` type column, so I have to sort it descending, and.. those answers below are true :D thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT person.id,
       person.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT fruit.apple) AS "Red Apple",
       fruit.*
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   tree
        ORDER  BY color DESC) AS fruit
       INNER JOIN people
         ON fruit.id = person.id
WHERE  person.name = 'John Smith' 
GROUP BY fruit.apple
```